# If there is only one zero value then group by supplier and show zero, if there is no zero, then avg all values

Tags: t-sql

I will give you example of table that I have:

```
Supplier | Value
sup1     |   4
sup2     |   1
sup1     |   0
sup1     |   3
sup2     |   5
```

I need a result that will do average by supplier, but if there is value 0 for a supplier, do not average, but return 0 instead

It should look like this:

```
Supplier | Value
sup1     |   0
sup2     |   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little trick but it should work :

```sql
SELECT  Supplier,
        CASE WHEN MIN(ABS(Value)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE AVG(Value) END 
FROM    TableTest
GROUP BY Supplier
```

**EDIT** : Using the ABS() function let you avoid having problems with negative values

Comment: I was doing the same, but without MIN(ABS( , and couldn't figure out what is missing

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (SUPPLIER VARCHAR(50),VALUE INTEGER)

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT 'sup1',4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sup2',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sup1',0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sup1',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sup2',5

SELECT * FROM @TAB

SELECT T1.SUPPLIER,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @TAB T WHERE T.SUPPLIER = T1.SUPPLIER AND T.VALUE = 0) THEN 0 ELSE AVG(T1.VALUE) END  AS VALUE
FROM @TAB T1
GROUP BY T1.SUPPLIER
```

Result

```
SUPPLIER    VALUE
sup1        0
sup2        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following query is one of the way to do.

First I push the supplier which has the Value = 0, then based on the result, I will do the remaining calculation and finally using UNION to get the expected result:

```
DECLARE @ZeroValue TABLE (Supplier VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO @ZeroValue (Supplier)
SELECT Supplier FROM TestTable WHERE Value = 0

SELECT Supplier, 0 AS Value FROM @ZeroValue
UNION
SELECT T.Supplier, AVG(T.Value) AS Value
FROM TestTable T
JOIN @ZeroValue Z ON Z.Supplier != T.Supplier
GROUP BY T.Supplier
```

Schema used for the sample:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Supplier VARCHAR (20), Value INT);

INSERT INTO TestTable (Supplier, Value) VALUES
('sup1', 4), ('sup2', 1), ('sup1', 0), ('sup1', 3), ('sup2', 5);
```

Please find the [**working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04d678b230af560a0f38174b3922cb7b)